# Why does Vue's <router-link> interfere with my HTML?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-router

So, when writing my CSS, I created a modal which opens when an invisible checkbox is clicked. Naturally, I used the `<label for = "">` hack to accommodate this; clicking the label activates the checkbox and opens the div. When I use the following html, this system works as expected:

```
<label class = "btn" for = "modal-1">+</label>
```

However, when I attempt to introduce a vue-router link to load content into the modal, things stop working:

```
<router-link to = "/classComp/create">
   <label class = "btn" for = "modal-1">+</label>
</router-link>
```

The above HTML successfully loads the code into the modal, but the modal remains invisible. For some reason, the router-link is activated but the label class is not. The `<router-view>` element renders thusly on my page:

```
<a href="/classComp/create" class=""><div class="addSidebar"><label for="modal-1" class="btn">+
            </label></div></a>
```

Does anyone know the cause of or solution to this error? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what CSS has to do with this